# Java Swing Windows LookAndFeel Issue when running on JDK11

Tags: java, swing, java-8, java-11

I have a problem with an old Java Swing application, which ran well till now on JRE8. However, I am experiencing a display Issue of JInternalFrame's title bar, when I build the application with JDK11 (with Java 8 compliance level) and run it on JRE11.

The problem is the look of the title bar of an JInternalFrame. In JRE8 everything looks good, however under JRE11 the title bar is smaller and the "close", "maximize" and "minimize" buttons are somewhat "squeezed". There is also no proper border around the whole frame in JRE11 and it looks like the title bar would be broader than the frame itself.

I am using the default system look and feel and run the application on Windows 10.

```java
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

How it looks in JRE8:

[image]

And how it looks in JRE11:

[image]

I have tried to set the dimensions of the title bar with the following code:

```java
((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI) getUI()).getNorthPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(103, 33));
```

But I only manage to make the title bar higher - it is not possible to make the min/max/close-buttons look properly.

I also have tried to compare the UIManager.defaults() between 8 and 11, but regarding the InternalFrame.* properties, they seem to have identical values for the both Java editions.

Does anybody have any ideas for this issue?

Comment: did you pack() it or set its size as recommended here? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Comment: I am not using pack(), I set the size with setSize()